# Keyboard shortcuts to acess and launch a specific Bookmark in Chrome on OS/X?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

The following *help* page from the chrome docs discusses how to use a keyboard shortcut to bring up the Bookmarks: `Command-Shift-B`.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95745?hl=en

We would still be left to using the mouse /trackpad to click on the specific  bookmark .. unless there were a means to tab through them: is there such a keyboard combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this chrome extention [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck)

[image: shortcut]

Another approach is to

- Move focus to the url bar with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- Type the full name of the bookmark followed by a <kbd>/</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the second autocompletion (which in my experience is always the first matching bookmark name).
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use to access my chrome bookmarks without using the mouse.  I'm on Mac, btw:

1. Focus on chrome using `command + tab`
2. `command + shift + /` focuses the menu bar Help option
3. Press `left arrow key` 4 times to highlight bookmarks
4. Press down arrow key until I get the bookmark I wanted
5. Press enter

Comment: Another way is to hit `Menubar` shortcut - which I changed to `Control-;` then type `b` then start typing the first letters of the shortcut

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking an extension, [QuicKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) lets you quickly search for a bookmark and open it in the same tab, a new tab or a new window, using just the keyboard.

- Press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to open the QuicKey menu (the default shortcut on Windows).
- Type <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to start a bookmark search.
- Type part of the bookmark's title or URL.
- Press <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> to select a bookmark, if the first result isn't what you want.
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to open the bookmark in the current tab, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to open it in a new tab, or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to open it in a new window.

If you just want to use the built-in tools, as of Chrome 63 when the Bookmarks page was redesigned, you can:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (on Windows) to open the Bookmarks manager.
- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> 3 times to navigate from the search bar to the bookmark folder list.
- Press <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> to move through the folders.
- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to move to the list of bookmarks in the folder.
- Press <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> to select a bookmark.
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to open the bookmark in a new tab.

You can also do a search on the Bookmarks page and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> 4 times to get to the results list and then arrow down to select a result.